# Testing token decode with Jest with VueJs

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, jwt

I have a method that accept a request like this:

```
{"token_type":"Bearer",
"expires_in":36000,
"access_token":"blabla",
"refresh_token":"blablbla"}

loginSuccessful (req) {
    const jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode')
    const decoded = jwtDecode(req.data.access_token)
    const role = decoded.scopes[0]
    this.toktok = req.data.access_token
    localStorage.role = role
    localStorage.token = req.data.access_token
    localStorage.refresh_token = req.data.refresh_token
  },
```

This method decode the token with jwt-decode and store the informations in localstorage
When I try to test this fonction :

```
it('Mounting Login successfully Method', () => {

    const response = {
      data:
        {
          token_type: 'Bearer',
          expires_in: 36000,
          access_token: 'dsqdsq',
          refresh_token: 'dqsdqs',}
      ,
    }
    const wrapper = mount(Login, {
      localVue,
      sync: false,
    })
    wrapper.vm.loginSuccessful(response)
    expect(localStorage.getItem('token')).toEqual(response.data.access_token)
    expect(localStorage.getItem('refresh_token')).toEqual(response.data.refresh_token)
  })
```

I got an error that decoded is undefined